# Is it possible to allow viewport zooming on iOS, yet lock certain elements from zooming?

Tags: ios, mobile, mobile-safari

Specifically, I want to allow the page to be zoomed at will using a typical viewport attributes, however I have one element on the page that I do NOT want to be scaled when zooming.  Is this possible?